# Can I fly to Germany from India?

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, germany, covid-19

India is currently a high risk area and there are strict restrictions. Germany are only allowing a small class of people who are satisfying criteria e.g., high skilled labor etc.

I have a flight from Frankfurt to Kolkata (Dec 13) and return on Jan 15. I work in Wurzburg. Currently, I have a provisional residence permit (Fiktionsbescheinigung).

I fall in the highly skilled labor class. I have a job contract. However, when you return from high risk area, are the border controls very strict? What kind of questions do they ask?

Comment: Not related to corona, but have you made sure that you have a Fiktionsbescheinigung, with which you are allowed to reenter Germany?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Travel rule in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161106/travel-rule-in-germany)

Comment: In terms of Covid, you won't be prevented from entering the country, but you will most likely will have to quarantine upon arrival. However, like others said, the rules are changing frequently, so best to keep on regularly checking the news and regulations relevant to your travel itinerary

Comment: Apart from permission, you might also have to take your chances on flights in January not being cancelled.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I have a § 81 Abs. 4 AufenthG. I checked with the German officials, they said it is allowed to go to your home country.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk, not completely. I wanted to know if some Bavarian rules might be important to take into account.

Comment: In order to increase your chances that the flights will actually happen, you might consider to use Air India rather than Lufthansa. In October, at least Lufthansa cancelled many of their flights.

Comment: I find it strange that this question has been closed, since it looks fine to me.

Comment: Another point to keep in mind: A Fiktionsbescheinigung is quite short-term. If somehow you do not make it back to Germany in time (and the probability of something like this happening is much higher than normal at the moment) things might get complicated.

Answer (score 18):

A few points

1. I've entered Germany from a risk area twice and never had to answer any questions at immigration at all. I do have a German passport though. Generally it falls to the airlines responsibility to make sure that no one enters a Germany bound plane who doesn't have the right to enter. Once I got to Germany, control and enforcement was basically non-existent (which was kind of scary).
2. Rules for entry and quarantine are confusing and in flux. Rules for quarantine and local travel are also made by they states, not the federal government. So you should study the current rules of Hessen (Frankfurt) and Bavaria (Wuerzburg). Sometimes the rules even vary from county to county.
3. Jan 15 is a long time away. The situation in Germany has gotten a lot worse since the summer and as a result the restrictions have been tightened up in November significantly. At this point no one knows what the rules in January will be. Rules can change very quickly.
4. Example: Bavaria updated their quarantine and travel rules last on Nov 5 going into effect Nov 9. These rules were supposed to apply until Nov  27 but no new ones have emerged yet and no one knows what's going to happen even next week.

Conclusion: the Covid pandemic is a global challenge. It's impossible to predict if or under what conditions you will be able to enter Germany on Jan 15. If you decide to travel, you have to accept the risk to be stuck in India for a while.

Comment: I think it is pretty safe to say that the current restrictions will a) be tightened even more and b) extended at least into January, maybe even until the end of flu season.

Comment: OTOH entry by people with a residency permit was allowed even in March/April, and the current state of travel restrictions is still considerably more lenient than back then. E.g. most land borders are still open, with the only exception so far being Saxony to Czech. Czech had one of the worst Covid waves last month, and the border was only closed after there was considerable splash-over.

Comment: you had to be in a quarantine for 2 weeks

Answer (score 5):

The rule has always been that people with a residency permit can enter Germany. This is AFAIK pretty standard as far as it comes to Covid-related entry requirements around the world.

> Deutsche Staatsangehörige sind von den Einschränkungen nicht betroffen.

> Auch Unionsbürger und Staatsangehörige des Vereinigten Königreichs, Liechtensteins, der Schweiz, Norwegens und Islands und ihre Familienangehörigen der Kernfamilie (Ehepartner, minderjährige ledige Kinder, Eltern minderjähriger Kinder) sind von den Einreisebeschränkungen ausgenommen.

> **Das gleiche gilt für Drittstaatsangehörige mit einem bestehenden längerfristigen Aufenthaltsrecht** in einem EU- oder Schengenstaat oder dem Vereinigten Königreich (Aufenthaltstitel oder längerfristiges Visum) und ihre Familienangehörigen der Kernfamilie.

(from https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/bevoelkerungsschutz/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html => "Welche Reisebeschränkungen gibt es im außereuropäischen Luft- und Seeverkehr?")

Your Fiktionsbescheinigung is probably due to § 81 Abs. 4 AufenthG, which means it is essentially an Aufenthaltstitel.

So once you make it to Germany on a plane, you should be able to enter. The more difficult problem may be getting the airport personnel in India to allow you to get on the plane, due to the unfamiliar combination of travel restrictions for non-residency permit holders and you only having a Fiktionsbescheinigung. Might be a good idea to check with the airline first, get some written reply and arrive early at the airport for your return trip in case there are problems.

---

Re. possible quarantine: My impression is that countries that are trying to eradicate Covid-19 have very strict quarantine rules (i.e. quarantine "hotels" that you cannot leave and have to pay for out of your own pocket). Sometimes these rules create a bottle neck because quarantine capacities are limited and so only a certain number of people can enter the country per week (e.g. in [Australia](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2020/nov/10/stranded-australians-hopes-of-returning-by-christmas-fading-as-numbers-swell), but I am familiar with at least one other country with the same problem)

Quarantine requirements in countries that do not fall into that category are considerably more lenient. Germany currently falls into the category of countries that do not really attempt to bring Covid cases to zero, and quarantine requirements are not very strict. I do not think this will change until January, but you might want to follow the news. And also note that there is a possibility that India might tighten some rules and air travel gets more limited as a result.

---

P.S. there is also a possibility that new entry requirements are added. One such requirement is already in force (registration at https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de/ ) but it is easy to imagine more might follow. This is also something to watch and keep in mind. E.g. if they, say, introduce a requirement for a negative Covid test before you can board the plane, you would have to prepare accordingly

---

Another point to keep in mind: A Fiktionsbescheinigung is quite short-term. If somehow you do not make it back to Germany in time (and the probability of something like this happening is much higher than normal at the moment) things might get complicated.