# Do children need a COVID test to enter Germany?

Tags: germany, covid-19

I am going from India to Germany (Frankfurt) next week (December 9th 2020) with my 4 months old baby. From Frankfurt airport we will travel to Karlsruhe.

We have a valid German visa. I know that I will need to get a COVID test within 48 hours from my flight to Germany, but what about my child?

Comment: Why do you believe that it is necessary for yourself to do a covid test?

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161323/can-i-fly-to-germany-from-india

Answer (score 1):

According to [Germany's FAQ on COVID testing](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-Einreisende-englisch.html), there aren't any exceptions for children. So your child will need to get a COVID test too, although note that you may also undergo the test after arriving to Germany in case babies are not eligible for testing in India.